# Laravel: HTML Editor for Newsletters

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I just wanted to ask this specific question although it might have been asked before and references are available because I'm still confused as how to implement this as I'm still a junior developer and still has a lot to learn.

Currently I made an admin site which is using Laravel, MySQL, and PHP7. Now my superiors wanted me to create a page where:

- Send a newsletter/marketing/promotions newsletter, where they have at least 10 html templates, pre made, and be able to edit them and save them in the database.
- Update those html templates and see the result at the same time. e.g. a split view of the update template while the other it the html code.

Is this possible with Laravel? They sent a sample media newsletter with an images that is part of the email. I have little clue as to how to implement this. Any advice, references, tutorials? Please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that by swapping the names. For example, every mail template has some basic structure. And within the structure, you will elements that are dynamic. For example, receiver name, his email address etc.

What you could is to save the template and then you can replace name strings. For example,

```
Hello %name%,

You are receiving this newsletter.

Thanks,
%company%
```

Save this template on your database and retrieve and replace the names when you need to send mail like

```
$content = GET FROM DATABASE BY YOUR LOGIC.
```

Then replace the

```
$content = str_ireplace(['%name%', '%company%'], ['John Doe', 'XYZ'], $content);
```

**For Editing**

For editing the template, you can simply load the content on a **text area** and allow admin users to edit them. Also, make sure you add a hint saying not to modify the dynamic variables inside the template like %name% while editing.